# libraries from pycharm vs pip, python 3.8

Tags: python

Why when I using `pip list` I am receiving libraries list,
but then i am checking in Pycharm, I have view more there for my project.

It means that using install `pip` I am installing libraries for all projects , but from Pycharm (in settings) only for selected project?

Comment: Yes, by default PyCharm will install packages for this specific project only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PyCharm, you work in a **Virtual Environment** also known as *venv*.
Installing packages there will not be installed globally.

For e.g.

In Pycharm, if you run `pip install tabulate` and then try importing `tabulate` outside PyCharm, it will show an `ImportError` and vice-versa

If you want to install that package for **all projects**, turn on *Make available to all projects* in project settings or while creating a new project.

To install package outside it, you will need to run `pip install <package-name>` in Command Prompt